# Is it possible to configure Kubernetes to deploy services in a specific order?

Tags: kubernetes, fluxcd

I have 3 services that are based on the same image, they're basically running the same app in 3 different configurations. 1 service is responsible for running migrations and data updates which the other 2 services will need. So I need this 1 service to be deployed first before the other 2 will be deployed. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the two services which are dependent on service 1 are either `Pod`, `Deployment` or `ReplicaSet`. So, make use of [Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/).

[Here is an example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#init-containers-in-use) that will make a pod wait until the dependent services are up and running. `busybox` is most common image used for init containers that supports variety of linux commands that will help you check the status of dependent services.

Comment: Since all 3 services are the same repository. When we update the image version in fluxcd, Isn't it up to K8s to decide which service will go first? And then say service 2 is deployed first, it would still get a successful response from the older pod of service 1 right?

Comment: Yes. I follow you. In that case you will have to go for something like blue-green deployment kind of service rollout. Example: https://www.haproxy.com/blog/rolling-updates-and-blue-green-deployments-with-kubernetes-and-haproxy/

Comment: thanks, I used the init containers and it works as expected

Answer (score 1):

I would look for a solution outside of Kubernetes.

Assuming that you have a release pipeline to deploy the changes, you could have a step to migrate and update the database. If the migration step succeeds, then deploy all the new services.

If you really have to use K8S, see the [InitContainers doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/).

Answer (score 0):

In flux there is an option to define the sequence of applications to be deployed.
With spec.dependsOn you can specify that the execution of a Kustomization follows another. When you add "dependsOn" entries to a Kustomization, that Kustomization is applied only after all of its dependencies are ready.

You can add under the spec of kustomization

spec:

dependsOn:

```
- name: dependency-kustomization
```